# Python - Summary Statistics using date and name

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series

In python, I have time series data. The key of the data is date and name, and the data has 4 attributes: A, B, C and D.

I need to do some summary data analysis on this dataset:

1) For each name, average of A, B, C and D

2) For each name, standard deviation of A, B, C, and D

3) For each name, count number of NaN's as a percentage of total for each A, B, C, and D

I am familiar with R but not python.  If you can point me in the right direction that would be more than enough!  Thank you.

```
asof_dt = pd.date_range('20151231','20160130')
df1=pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(len(asof_dt),4),index=asof_dt,columns=('A','B','C','D'))
df1['name']='alpha'
df2=pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(len(asof_dt),4),index=asof_dt,columns=('A','B','C','D'))
df2['name']='beta'
df3=pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(len(asof_dt),4),index=asof_dt,columns=('A','B','C','D'))
df3['name']='gama'
df_total = pd.concat([df1,df2,df3])
df_total[['name','A','B','C']]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is [groupBy](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html).

For your example:

```
import pandas as pd

df_total.groupby(['name']).mean()
df_total.groupby(['name']).std()
df_total.groupby(['name']).apply(pd.isnull).sum() / df_total.groupBy(['name']).size()
```

Comment: Seems like everything works when I change the "groupBy" to lowercase "groupby".  However, the last one doesn't work:

AttributeError: Cannot access callable attribute 'isnull' of 'DataFrameGroupBy' objects, try using the 'apply' method

Comment: @TrexionKameha: That's what I get for posting code without running it first :). You can use `apply` with the `pandas.isnull` function to achieve the same effect, see edit.

Comment: To get the % NaN, you should divide by the total number (the length), not the number of non Null values provided by `count`.

Comment: @Alexander Ah, of course. I edited the answer to use `size` instead, which should get the same as `len` for each group.

Answer (score 1):

`describe` gives you quite a bit of information:

```
>>> df_total.describe()

               A          B          C          D
count  93.000000  93.000000  93.000000  93.000000
mean    0.006006   0.136171   0.024950   0.039227
std     0.987713   0.996221   1.042611   0.946783
min    -2.193879  -2.958631  -3.012410  -2.714318
25%    -0.604479  -0.436393  -0.514906  -0.574699
50%     0.012784   0.191079   0.062942   0.087534
75%     0.535302   0.701117   0.666500   0.833580
max     2.578850   2.483724   2.460043   2.282775
```

To just get the count, mean and SD:

```
>>> df_total.groupby('name').apply(lambda group: group.describe().head(3))

    A          B          C          D
name                                                   
alpha count  31.000000  31.000000  31.000000  31.000000
      mean   -0.076509   0.152993   0.149915   0.180412
      std     1.056520   1.063591   1.010325   0.778637
beta  count  31.000000  31.000000  31.000000  31.000000
      mean    0.022814   0.247238  -0.006391   0.059466
      std     0.862030   0.870068   1.065224   1.055671
gama  count  31.000000  31.000000  31.000000  31.000000
      mean    0.071712   0.008283  -0.068673  -0.122199
      std     1.058608   1.060826   1.073273   0.990097
```

Comment: Is there an easy way for a count of NaN?

Comment: To get % NaN: `df_total.groupby('name').apply(lambda group: group.isnull().sum().div(len(group)))`